# "Italian stock market" vs "Italy stock market" and "Hong Kong stock market" vs "Hong Kongese stock market"

Tags: adjectives

I have seen both "China stock market" and "Chinese stock market" multiple times. But I never saw "Italy stock market" or "Hong Kongese stock market" once.

Moreover, I found a paper titled *An analysis of the January effect of United States, Taiwan and South Korean stock returns*.

It's no consistent, I mean, why it's "South Korean stock returns" rather than "South Korea stock returns"

Comment: In my experience, stock markets are usually called by their city (Toronto, London, Tokyo, Shanghai), or by a specific index (NASDAQ, FTSE, Hang Seng, DAX, etc). I've rarely heard of a market referred to by its country.

Comment: A lot of papers suffer from poor translation or are not properly edited.

Answer (score 1):

*South Korea* is a noun. *South Korean* is an adjective.

However, the only stock market in Korea is the [Korea Exchange](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korea_Exchange), so it looks like *Korea* is one of those nouns that can modify some words but not others.

There may not be any hard and fast rules. It’s hard to turn an abbreviation like U.K. or U.S. into an adjective. The adjectives for countries like Taiwan, Japan, and Madagascar are unwieldy, as is the adjective for Panama, where *Panamanian* sounds too much like *mania*.

Korea, on the other hand, is easy for English-speakers to use either way.

In the example you cite, *Taiwan* came between *United States* and *Korea*. The author chose *Taiwan* over *Taiwanese* because it sounded nicer to his or her ears.

Comment: Names tend to be ideosyncratic like this. We have New York Stock Exchange but not America Stock Exchange.